# About Assistat T-Shirt after creating the very first action on google app

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

I have submitted My First Action on Google app on Nov. 2018, I have read on google that google provides welcome tshirt but still i have not get any mail from google assistant team about this, so when can i expect this from google ?

Answer (score 0):

Good morning, Tejas! You can contact the support team here to get this resolved:

https://developers.google.com/actions/support/